# Random characters printed after printing 'result'

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, c-strings, getchar

I'm getting random characters after the actual output in `printf("%s",result);`. 
Why are these characters being printed? And how can I remove them?

```
#include<stdio.h>
char *replacechar(char[]);

int main()
{
    char str[25];
    char *result;
    int i=0;
    while( (str[i++]=getchar()) != '\n' && i < 25);
    result= replacechar(str);
    printf("%s",result);
    return 0;
}

char *replacechar(char str[])
{
    return str;
}
```

### Expected Output:

```
aaayt
aaayt
```

### Actual Output:

```
aaayt
aaayt
↑@
```

Comment: you need to complete the string with NULL character. Add `str[i] = '\0'` after the while statement.

Comment: Because you never added a null terminator after the last character. Also, `char str[25];` only has room for 24 characters plus the `'\0`' null terminator character, so you may want to increase its size to 26 or change `i < 25` to `i < 24`.

Comment: Remember that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you! It worked. But I can't seem to mark this comment as the answer.

Comment: Note: good first posting, even if a common question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters the operands of the condition

```
(str[i++]=getchar()) != '\n' && i < 25
```

should be swapped.

```
i < 25 && (str[i++]=getchar()) != '\n'
```

The input stored in the character array str should be zero-terminated. Otherwise the array will not contain a string.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how your code can be rewritten

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *replacechar( char str[] )
{
    return str;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 25 };
    char str[N];
    char *result;

    size_t i = 0;

    while( i < N - 1 && ( str[i] = getchar() ) != '\n' ) i++;

    str[i] = '\0';

    result = replacechar( str );

    puts( result ); 

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Hello Siddharth Awana
Hello Siddharth Awana
```